# Split 1 argument into 2 arguments using regexp in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash

Here's my situation.  Currently, I have a script that accepts two arguments: book name and chapter name.  For example:

```
$ myscript book1 chap1
```

Now, for reasons that would take a long time to explain, I would prefer my script to be able to take a single argument of the following format: {book name}.{chapter name}.  For example:

```
$ myscript book1.chap1
```

The difficulty for me is that I do not know how to take a string $1=abc.xyz and turn it into two separate variables, $var1=abc and $var2=xyz.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's just two tags you can use a bash expression

```
arg=$1
beforedot=${arg%.*}
afterdot=${arg#*.}
```

It's faster than `cut` because it's a shell builtin. Note that this puts everything before the <strike>first</strike> last dot into `beforedot` and everything after into `afterdot`.

**EDIT**:

There's also a substitution/reinterpretation construct if you want to split by an arbitrary number of tokens:

```
string=a.b.c.d.e
tokens=(${string//\./ })
```

You're replacing dots by spaces and then that gets interpreted as an array declaration+definition because of the parentheses around it.

However I've found this to be less portable to bash' siblings and offspring. For example, it doesn't work in my favourite shell, `zsh`.

Arrays need to be dereferenced with braces and are indexed from 0:

```
echo "Third token: ${tokens[2]}"
```

You can loop through them as well by dereferencing the whole array with [@]:

```
for i in ${tokens[@]}
do
    # do stuff
done
```

Comment: What happens if the string contains more than one dot?

Comment: If `$arg="start.middle.end"`, then afterwards `$beforedot="start.middle"`, and `$afterdot="middle.end"`.  The middle part would be duplicated.

Comment: @mouviciel: the section between dots winds up in both variables (e.g. if $1="a.b.c.d", it'll set $beforedot="a.b.c" and $afterdot="b.c.d").  If you use `beforedot=${arg%%.*}`, you'll get just the part before the first dot in $beforedot, which might make more sense.

Comment: The name of this sort of thing is parameter expansion for those who want further reading: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 2):

For completeness and since you asked about a regex method:

```
pattern='^([^.]*)\.(.*)'
[[ $1 =~ $pattern ]]
book=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
chapter=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

The capture groups are elements in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. Element 0 contains the whole match.

This regex will capture up to the first dot in the first element. Anything after the first dot including susbsequent dots will be in the second element. The regex can be easily modified to break on the last dot if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If `$arg` contains `book.chap`

```
read BOOK CHAP<<<$(IFS="."; echo $arg)
```

will set the variables BOOK and CHAP accordingly. This uses the bash internal field separator (IFS) which controls how bash understands word boundaries. If (say) you have multiple separators in your original `$arg` then just specify further variables to contain the results.

From [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html):

> $IFS defaults to whitespace (space, tab, and newline), but may be
>   changed, for example, to parse a comma-separated data file

Comment: `IFS=. read -r book chapter <<<"$1"` is cleaner. No need for the `echo` or the command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses to capture the two parts; afterwards, you can use backreferences to grab them again. The syntax differs between languages; check http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for a lesson on backreferences in general.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I've done this type of grouping regex matching in Python, but I've never used regex's in bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

book=${1%.*}
chapter=${1#*.}

printf 'book: %s\nchapter: %s\n' "$book" "$chapter"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pattern Subsitution with Shell Parameter Expansion

There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. One of the ways not covered in other answers is [pattern substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

If you know that the value will always split correctly on a period, you can apply pattern substitution to the value so that it will be easy to tokenize with *IFS*. For example:

```
set -- foo.bar
myvar="${1/./ }"
echo $myvar
```

This will yield `foo bar`.