# How to get bc to handle numbers in scientific (aka exponential) notation?

Tags: bash, numeric, floating-accuracy, bc

`bc` doesn't like numbers expressed in scientific notation (aka exponential notation).

```
$ echo "3.1e1*2" | bc -l
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

but I need to use it to handle a few records that are expressed in this notation. Is there a way to get `bc` to understand exponential notation? If not, what can I do to translate them into a format that `bc` will understand?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Unfortunately, bc doesn't support scientific notation.

However, it can be translated into a format that bc can handle, using [extended regex as per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) in sed:

```
sed -E 's/([+-]?[0-9.]+)[eE]\+?(-?)([0-9]+)/(\1*10^\2\3)/g' <<<"$value"
```

you can replace the "e" (or "e+", if the exponent is positive) with "*10^", which bc will promptly understand. This works even if the exponent is negative or if the number is subsequently multiplied by another power, and allows keeping track of significant digits.

If you need to stick to basic regex (BRE), then this should be used:

```
sed 's/\([+-]\{0,1\}[0-9]*\.\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\)[eE]+\{0,1\}\(-\{0,1\}\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/(\1*10^\2\3)/g' <<<"$value"
```

---

From Comments:

- A simple bash [pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) match could not work (thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)) as there is no way to match a e+ and keep the - from a e- at the same time.
- A correctly working perl solution (thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0))

  ```
  $ perl -pe 's/([-\d.]+)e(?:\+|(-))?(\d+)/($1*10^$2$3)/gi' <<<"$value"
  ```
- Thanks to [@jwpat7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837847/james-waldby-jwpat7) and [@Paul Tomblin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3333/paul-tomblin) for clarifying aspects of sed's syntax, as well as [@isaac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9110606/isaac) and [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for improving the answer.

Edit:

The answer changed quite a bit over the years. The answer above is the latest iteration as of 17th May 2018. Previous attempts reported here were a solution in pure bash (by [@ormaaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495451/ormaaj)) and one in sed (by [@me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714385/ferdinando-randisi)), that fail in at least some cases. I'll keep them here just to make sense of the comments, which contain much nicer explanations of the intricacies of all this than this answer does.

```
value=${value/[eE]+*/*10^}  ------> Can not work.
value=`echo ${value} | sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'` ------> Fail in some conditions
```

Comment: Two successive bash substitutions will work (i.e. `v=${v/e/*10^};` `v=${v/^+/^}`), provided the result isn't used in an expression with higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that when the superscript on the exponential is negative, one has to specify the `scale` in `bc`, otherwise one may get unexpected `0`.

Answer (score 24):

Let me try to **summarize** the existing answers, with **comments on each below**:

- (a) If you indeed need to use **`bc` for *arbitrary*-precision calculations** - as the OP does - use the [OP's own clever approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882612/45375), which ***textually* reformats the scientific notation to an *equivalent expression*** that `bc` understands.
- **If *potentially losing precision* is *not* a concern**,

  - (b) consider using **`awk` or `perl` as `bc` alternatives**; both natively understand scientific notation, as demonstrated in [jwpat7's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884071/45375) answer for awk.
  - (c) consider using **`printf '%.<precision>f'`** to simply ***textually convert* to regular floating point representation (decimal fractions, without the `e`/`E`)** (a solution proposed in a since-deleted post by [ormaaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495451/ormaaj)).

---

#### (a) Reformatting scientific notation to an equivalent `bc` *expression*

The advantage of this solution is that **precision is preserved**: the textual representation is transformed into an *equivalent* textual representation that `bc` can understand, and `bc` itself is capable of arbitrary-precision calculations.

See the [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882612/45375), whose updated form is now capable of transforming an entire expression containing multiple numbers in exponential notation into an equivalent `bc` expression.

---

#### (b) Using `awk` or `perl` instead of `bc` as the calculator

Note: The following approaches assume use of the **built-in support for double-precision floating-point values in `awk` and `perl`**. 
As is in inherent in floating-point arithmetic,
<sup>"given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This **rounding error** is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation." (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)</sup>

That said,

- *GNU* awk offers the *option* to be *built with* support for arbitrary-precision arithmetic - see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gawk-and-MPFR.html; however, distributions *may or may not* include that support - verify support by checking the output from `gawk --version` for `GNU MPFR` and `GNU MP`.
  If support *is* available, you must activate it with `-M` (`--bignum`) in a given invocation.
- Perl offers *optional* arbitrary-precision decimal support via the `Math::BigFloat` package - see https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat

**awk**

**`awk` natively understands decimal exponential (scientific) notation.**
(You should generally only use *decimal* representation, because `awk` implementations differ with respect to whether they support number literals with other bases.)

```
awk 'BEGIN { print 3.1e1 * 2 }'  # -> 62
```

If you use the default `print` function, the `OFMT` variable controls the output format by way of a `printf` format string; the (POSIX-mandated) **default is `%.6g`, meaning 6 *significant digits*, which notably *includes the digits in the integer part***.

Note that if the number in scientific notation is supplied as *input* (as opposed to a literal part of the awk program), you must add `+0` to force it to the default output format, if used *by itself* with `print`:

<sup>Depending on your locale and the `awk` implementation you use, you may have to replace the decimal *point* (`.`) with the locale-appropriate radix character, such as `,` in a German locale; applies to BSD `awk`, `mawk`, and to GNU `awk` with the `--posix` option.</sup>

```
awk '{ print $1+0 }' <<<'3.1e1' # -> 31; without `+0`, output would be the same as input
```

Modifying **variable `OFMT`** changes the default output format (for numbers with fractional parts; (effective) integers are always output as such).
Alternatively, use the **`printf` function** with an explicit output format:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "%.4f", 3.1e1 * 2.1234 }' # -> 65.8254
```

**Perl**

**`perl` too natively understands decimal exponential (scientific) notation.**

**Note: Perl, unlike awk, isn't available on all POSIX-like platforms by default**; furthermore, it's **not as lightweight as awk**.
However, it offers **more features than awk, such as natively understanding hexadecimal and octal integers**.

```
perl -le 'print 3.1e1 * 2'  # -> 62
```

**I'm unclear on what Perl's default output format is, but it appears to be `%.15g`**.
As with awk, you can use `printf` to choose the desired output format:

```
perl -e 'printf "%.4f\n", 3.1e1 * 2.1234' # -> 65.8254
```

---

#### (c) Using `printf` to convert scientific notation to decimal fractions

If you simply want to convert scientific notation (e.g., `1.2e-2`) into a decimal fraction (e.g., `0.012`), `printf '%f'` can do that for you.
Note that you'll **convert one *textual* representation into *another*** via **floating-point arithmetic**, which is subject to the **same rounding errors as the `awk` and `perl` approaches**.

```
printf '%.4f' '1.2e-2' # -> '0.0120'; `.4` specifies 4 decimal digits.
```

Comment: Use Perl6/Raku with rational number arithmetic better than any language around today, https://www.quora.com/What-can-Perl-6-do-that-Python-cannot.

Answer (score 12):

One can use awk for this; for example,

```
awk '{ print +$1, +$2, +$3 }' <<< '12345678e-6 0.0314159e2 54321e+13'
```

produces (via awk's default format %.6g) output like
`12.3457 3.14159 543210000000000000`
while commands like the following two produce the output shown after each, given that file `edata` contains data as shown later.

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)printf"%.13g ",+$i; printf"\n"}' < edata`
31 0.0312 314.15 0 
123000 3.1415965 7 0.04343 0 0.1 
1234567890000 -56.789 -30 

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)printf"%9.13g ",+$i; printf"\n"}' < edata
       31    0.0312    314.15         0 
   123000 3.1415965         7   0.04343         0       0.1 
1234567890000   -56.789       -30 


$ cat edata 
3.1e1 3.12e-2 3.1415e+2 xyz
123e3 0.031415965e2 7 .4343e-1 0e+0 1e-1
.123456789e13 -56789e-3 -30
```

Also, regarding solutions using `sed`, it probably is better to delete the plus sign in forms like `45e+3` at the same time as the `e`, via regex `[eE]+*`, rather than in a separate `sed` expression.  For example, on my linux machine with GNU sed version 4.2.1 and bash version 4.2.24, commands
`sed 's/[eE]+*/*10^/g' <<< '7.11e-2 + 323e+34'`
`sed 's/[eE]+*/*10^/g' <<< '7.11e-2 + 323e+34' | bc -l`
produce output
`7.11*10^-2 + 323*10^34`
`3230000000000000000000000000000000000.07110000000000000000`

Comment: uhm, so awk handles significant digits correctly. That is interesting. The only drawback I can see is that this way you have to set a maximum precision to your numbers, which if exceeded would make the script not work properly.

If there was a way to force awk to use arbitrary precision it would be perfect.

I like better your version of the sed command rather than my own, I forgot about the possibilities of *.

Comment: @Ferdinando, yes, awk has the drawbacks you mention, and its real numbers typically are doubles with 16 digit resolution; for example, `awk '{printf"%.40g",+$1}' <<<  12345678901234567891234567890123456e-20` produces `123456789012.345672607421875`

Comment: Great alternative to `bc`, if potentially losing precision is not a concern; Note that the _portable_ way to force something into a number in `awk` is to append `+0`, not to prepend `+`. For instance, while `awk '{ print +$1 }' <<<1e-1` works fine in `mawk` and `gawk` (outputs `0.1`), it does _not_ in BSD awk (as used on OS X; outputs the input unmodified). By contrast, `awk '{ print $1+0 }' <<<1e-1` should work with _all_ awk implementations.

Answer (score 10):

You can also define a bash function which calls awk (a good name would be the equal sign "="):

```
= ()
{
    local in="$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's/\[/(/g' -e 's/\]/)/g')";
    awk -v CONVFMT=%.15g 'BEGIN {print '"$in"' ""}' < /dev/null
}
```

Then you can use all type of floating point math in the shell. Note that square brackets are used here instead of round brackets, since the latter would have to be protected from the bash by quotes.

```
> = 1+sin[3.14159] + log[1.5] - atan2[1,2] - 1e5 + 3e-10
-99999.058179847
```

Or in a script to assign the result

```
a=$(= 1+sin[4])
echo $a   # 0.243198
```

Comment: I like this solution very much, provided I don't find any pitfalls. I have to do basic arithmetic with scientific notation so often and this works a charm so far. For now I have defined your function in my bash_profile and named it scmath. Using the = symbol seems a bit dangerous to me

Comment: I might be wrong here, but the answer to `1+sin[3.14159] + log[1.5] - atan2[1,2] - 1e5 + 3e-10` is for sure not `0.94182`

Comment: @jo-h `python3 -c "from math import *;print(1+sin(3.14159) + log(1.5) - atan2(1,2) - 1e5 + 3e-10)"` returns `-99999.058179847` and after executing your `=` function on my Linux it returns `-99999.1` (but not `0.94182`). I conclude your `=` function is correct, congratulations :+1: !

Comment: I like it. Note shell metacharacters like * ( ) MAY need to be escaped or the whole expression quoted. Especially if there are spaces in the expression. 'x' is a non-metachar that does multiplication substituting for *.

Answer (score 4):

Luckily there is printf, which does the formatting job:

The above example:

```
printf "%.12f * 2\n" 3.1e1 | bc -l
```

Or a float comparison:

```
n=8.1457413437133669e-02
m=8.1456839223809765e-02

n2=`printf "%.12f" $n`
m2=`printf "%.12f" $m`

if [ $(echo "$n2 > $m2" | bc -l) == 1  ]; then 
   echo "n is bigger"
else
   echo "m is bigger"
fi
```

Comment: This works, but will fail on small numbers (10^-12)

Answer (score 1):

Piping version of OPs accepted answer

```
$ echo 3.82955e-5 | sed 's/[eE]+*/\*10\^/'
3.82955*10^-5
```

Piping the input to the OPs accepted sed command gave extra backslashes like

```
$ echo 3.82955e-5 | sed 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'
3.82955\*10\^-5
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with a little hack. You can do something like this -

```
scientific='4.8844221e+002'
base=$(echo $scientific | cut -d 'e' -f1)
exp=$(($(echo $scientific | cut -d 'e' -f2)*1))
converted=$(bc -l <<< "$base*(10^$exp)")
echo $converted 
>> 488.4422100
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (found this in an example for a CFD input data for processing with m4:)

```
T0=4e-5
deltaT=2e-6
m4 <<< "esyscmd(perl -e 'printf (${T0} + ${deltaT})')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (using bash)

```
printf "scale=20\n0.17879D-13\n" | sed -e 's/D/*10^/' | bc
```

or this:

```
 num="0.17879D-13"; convert="`printf \"scale=20\n$num\n\" | sed -e 's/D/*10^/' | bc`" ; echo $convert
.00000000000001787900
num="1230.17879"; convert="`printf \"scale=20\n$num\n\" | sed -e 's/D/*10^/' | bc`" ; echo $convert
1230.17879
```

If you have positive exponents you should use this:

```
num="0.17879D+13"; convert="`printf \"scale=20\n$num\n\" | sed -e 's/D+/*10^/' -e 's/D/*10^/' | bc`" ; echo $convert
1787900000000.00000
```

That last one would handle every numbers thrown at it. You can adapt the 'sed' if you have numbers with 'e' or 'E' as exponents.

You get to chose the scale you want.

Answer (score 0):

From a floating point perspective, there is a difference between the scientific representation (e.g. `1.1E2`), and its seemingly equivalent numeric base-10 computation (`1.1*10^2`). The main reason is that some numbers cannot be accurately represented as a binary number. Hence, floating point errors will be introduced in the computation (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8344060))

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.17f"; print 1.1e2; print 1.1*10**2}'
110
110.00000000000001421
```

The solution would then be to change the format of the floating point number and not to convert it into a computation. As mentioned in other posts, `printf` is the solution here, however one has to be careful with small and big numbers as the example shows (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36334933/8344060)):

```
v=3.2e-3
printf -- "%.12f" "$v"
0.003200000000
$ v=3.2e-13
$ printf -- "%.12f" "$v"
0.000000000000
```

So it would be nice to transfer the information of the exponent to `printf` by defining the precision as an argument. The following conversion does this

```
$ printf -- "%.*f" $((17-${v#*[eE]})) "$v"
```

This takes into account that you need 17 digits precision to represent a double-precision floating point number accurately and it exploits the fact that `printf` converts a negative precision into a default precision.
Here are some examples:

```
for v in 1.2345678901234567e{-2,+2,-10,+10,-20,+20}; do 
   printf -- "%.*f\n" $((17-${v#*[eE]})) "${v}"
done
0.0123456789012345670
123.456789012345670
0.000000000123456789012345670
12345678901.2345670
0.0000000000000000000123456789012345670
123456789012345670000.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my little `perlCalc` bash function :

```bash
perlCalc ()
{
    set -- ${@/^/**}
    set -- ${@/[/(}
    set -- ${@/]/)}
    \perl -le "print $*"
}
```

Example :

```
$ perlCalc 1+sin[3.14159] + log[1.5] - atan2[1,2] - 1e5 + 3e-10
-99999.058179847
```

It returns the same result as python3 :

```py
$ python3 -c "from math import *;print(1+sin(3.14159) + log(1.5) - atan2(1,2) - 1e5 + 3e-10)"
-99999.058179847
```