# cut string in a specific column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

How can I cut the leading zeros in the third field so it will only be 6 characters?

```
 xxx,aaa,00000000cc
 rrr,ttt,0000000yhh
```

desired output

```
  xxx,aaa,0000cc
  rrr,ttt,000yhh
```

Comment: How are you deciding how many zeros to cut off?

Comment: Are you assuming you are always cutting off the same number of characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or here's a solution using awk

```
 echo " xxx,aaa,00000000cc
 rrr,ttt,0000000yhh"|awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/^0000/, "", $3)}1'
```

**output**

```
 xxx,aaa,0000cc
 rrr,ttt,000yhh
```

awk uses -F (or FS for FieldSeparator) and you must use OFS for OutputFieldSeparator) .

`sub(/srchtarget/, "replacmentstring", stringToFix)` is uses a regular expression to look for 4 `0`s at the front of (`^`) the third field ($3).

The `1` is a shorthand for the `print` statement. A longhand version of the script would be

```
echo " xxx,aaa,00000000cc
 rrr,ttt,0000000yhh"|awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/^0000/, "", $3);print}'
 # ---------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

Its all related to awk's `/pattern/{action}` idiom.

IHTH

Comment: Much better answer than mine. Would you mind explaining what that `1` at the end does?

Comment: @AndrewMagee : Better, well, shorter, anyway. Thanks. I've added a short explanation. If you read `awk` postings for a week or so, you'll find fuller definitions of how the `/pattern/{action}` works. Good luck to all.

Comment: @AndrewMagee: `1` is shorthand for: print the (potentially modified) line at hand unconditionally. Technically, `1` serves as a _pattern_ that always evaluates to true (non-negative numbers in awk are considered true in a Boolean context). awk programs come in pattern-action pairs: if the pattern matches, the associated action (`{...}`) is executed. Patterns that do not have an associated default to printing the line at hand. In `awk`, much is about what's left _unsaid_; the cleverly designed default behavior allows for very terse programs.

Comment: @mklement0 : Well put! Thanks for that. Good luck to all. Wow! Love your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882611/how-to-get-bc-to-handle-numbers-in-scientific-aka-exponential-notation/28846040#28846040 .

Comment: @shellter: thanks - almost: of course, I meant to say: _nonzero_ numbers in awk are considered true in a Boolean context -- and thanks for the compliment on the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume there are always three fields and you want to strip off the first four zeros in the third field you could use a monstrosity like this:

```
$ cat data
xxx,0000aaa,00000000cc
rrr,0000ttt,0000000yhh

$ cat data |sed 's/\([^,]\+\),\([^,]\+\),0000\([^,]\+\)/\1,\2,\3/
xxx,0000aaa,0000cc
rrr,0000ttt,000yhh
```

Another more flexible solution if you don't mind piping into Python:

```
cat data | python -c '
import sys
for line in sys.stdin():
  print(",".join([f[4:] if i == 2 else f for i, f in enumerate(line.strip().split(","))]))
'
```

This says "remove the first four characters of the third field but leave all other fields unchanged".

Comment: how if I also have 4 leading zeros at another column that i don't need to cut? I just need the 3rd column.. thanks

Comment: I may consider this one. But how about if I have more than 15 columns and I will only remove particular leading zeros in column 3, isn't it tedious?

Comment: It is a little bit tedious. Though it doesn't matter how many columns you have *after* the one you want to modify as you can just match a `.*` at the end.

Comment: Actually it will already work regardless of how many columns you have after the one you want to modify; they'll just remain unchanged. If you wanted to modify the 15th column, though, this solution would be a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`s  `substr` should also work:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3=substr($3,5,6)}1' file
xxx,aaa,0000cc
rrr,ttt,000yhh
```

It just take `6` characters from `5` position in field `3` and set it back to field `3`