# applying cut a second time to specific field/column in bash

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I'm trying to display part of the content of a file.
I currently use the following code to cut and format the fields I'm interested in

```
CONTENT="(cat foo.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1,4,5)"
TOPRINT=$(printf "%7s  %10s  %14s\n" $(eval $CONTENT))
```

Now my problem is I would like to further edit the 5th field that looks like

```
bla=0.,bleh=2.,name=hello_im_here
```

as the only part I want to display is the name ("hello_im_here").
I'm guessing I could use awk (as is done in [cut string in a specific column in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845033/cut-string-in-a-specific-column-in-bash%22cut%20string%20in%20a%20specific%20column%20in%20bash%22)) but as I'm not at all familiar with this command, I would appreciate more specific input on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to make yourself familiar with `awk`?

Comment: Maybe I should have emphasized that I don't see how to deal with _only_ the 5th field of my file while leaving the rest untouched. Otherwise I would not ask. And as the title suggests I would rather use cut if possible because it makes the code easier to read for users.

Comment: So what did you try to make it work with `cut`?

Comment: I tried using arrays `ARR1=$(cat foo.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1,4)` and `ARR2=$(cat foo.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -d '=' -f -1)` but then I don't know how to stack them in the `printf` line. I tried 
`TOPRINT=$(paste  < ("%7s  %10s\n" "${(eval $CONTENT)[@]}"))`
but this does work and I don't know why

Also this doesn't feel like the most elegant solution even then, so I favored asking for the core question.

Comment: Question is not very clear.  Giving us a sample of `foo.dat` and an expected output is your best bet to get a fitting answer.

Comment: Thank you for this constructive feedback. I'll apply it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTENT=$(awk '{gsub(" *.*=","",$5); printf "%7s  %10s  %14s\n",$1,$4,$5}' foo.dat)
echo $CONTENT
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of `cat`, why not `awk '{...}' foo.dat` or `awk '{...}' <foo.dat` ? As a rule of thumb, any time  you catch yourself wanting to do `cat something | ...`, it is most likely an UUOC.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin; you are right. I updated ans. thanks.

Comment: Sure, it takes everyone a while to break that habit (me included `:)`

Comment: @MustafaDOGRU Please don't recommend to use `eval()` here. That's crap!!