# sed pattern parts as input for other bash function

Tags: bash, sed, echo, bc

I'm trying to replace floating-point numbers like 1.2e + 3 with their integer value 1200. For this I use sed in the following way:

```
 echo '"1.2e+04"' | sed "s/\"\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)e+\([0-9]\+\)\"/$(echo \1*10^\2|bc -l)/"
```

but the pattern parts `\1` and `\2` doesn't get evaluated in the echo.

Is there a way to solve this problem with sed?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See [How to get bc to handle numbers in scientific (aka exponential) notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882611/how-to-get-bc-to-handle-numbers-in-scientific-aka-exponential-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the double quotes, `\1` and `\2` are interpreted as literal `1` and `2`.
You need to put additional backslashes to escape them. In addition, `$(command substitution)` in
`sed` replacement seems not to work when combined with back references.
If you are using `GNU sed`, you can instead say something like:

```
echo '"1.2e+04"' | sed "s/\"\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)e+\([0-9]\+\)\"/echo \"\\1*10^\\2\"|bc -l/;e"
```

which yields:

```
12000.0
```

If you want to chop off the decimal point, you'll know what to do ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with `awk` command like this can do the work:

```
echo 1.2e+4|awk '{printf "%d",$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps better to use `perl` (or other typed language) to manage the variable types:

`echo '"1.2e+04"' | perl -lane 'my $a=$_;$a=~ s/"//g;print sprintf("%.10g",$a);print $a;'`

<s>In any case, your `sed` expression is incorrect, it should be:</s>

<s>`echo '"1.2e+04"' | sed "s/\"\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)e+\([0-9]\+\)\"/$(echo \1*10^\3 + \2*10^$(echo \3 - 1 | bc -l)|bc -l)/"`</s>

Comment: how you are getting the value for `\3` in `sed` command, also i believe the output of your `sed` command should be `12000` instead of `1200` .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the problem properly is to use an advanced combination of @ tshiono and @ Romeo solutions:

```
sed "s/\(.*\)\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+e+[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/printf '\1'\; echo \2 |awk '{printf \"%d\",\$0}'\;printf '\3'\;/e"
```

So it is possible to convert all such floats into arbitrary contexts.

for example:

```
echo '"1.2e+04"' | sed "s/\(.*\)\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+e+[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/printf '\1'\; echo \2 |awk '{printf \"%d\",\$0}'\;printf '\3'\;/e"
```

outputs

```
"12000"
```

and

```
echo 'abc"1.2e+04"def' | sed "s/\(.*\)\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+e+[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/printf '\1'\; echo \2 |awk '{printf \"%d\",\$0}'\;printf '\3'\;/e"
```

outputs

```
abc"12000"def
```