# How to handle floating point division for large numbers using bc in bash?

Tags: bc

I am trying to calculate percentages with large numbers using the exponential notation. However, when doing this on bash using bc, I get what I presume to be is overflow errors.

For example, in bash if I do the calculation:

```
$ echo "6139391.0 / 2.9960647E7" | bc -l
2049151.60918664203376373104
```

The calculation is off. It should be `0.20491516755`.

How do I handle cases like this using bc or bash in general?

Comment: Yes, I inputted the two numbers into a calculator and that was the reason why I put it as why that should be the answer.

Comment: I've put it in multiple calculators and confirmed that is the number. The formula would indeed produce that output.

Comment: Apparently bc can't handle scientific notation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882612/4162356

Answer (score 0):

Overflow? 
No; it's just ignoring the exponent; it's giving you 6139391.0 / 2.9960647.

Try

```
echo "6139391.0 / 2.9960647E7" | sed -E 's/([0-9.]*)E([+-]*[0-9]*)/(\1*10^\2)/g' | bc -l
```

to convert `2.9960647E7` to `(2.9960647*10^7)`.

Answer (score 0):

`bc` does not support scientific notation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882611/how-to-get-bc-to-handle-numbers-in-scientific-aka-exponential-notation) for a workaround.