# Loop increasement with 0.5

Tags: bash, file, loops

I have loop which writes to file, but I want to write each 0.5 value to the file. I tried with `let count+=0.5` but that didn't work somehow. Is this possible?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=50
count=0
until [  $COUNTER -lt 20 ]; do
        echo $count >> value.txt
        echo COUNTER $COUNTER
        let COUNTER-=1
        let count+=0.5
        sleep 1
done
```

Comment: BashFAQ #22: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022

Comment: ...also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222250/floating-point-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` doesn't do floating-point arithmetic natively; you need to use an external tool. `-=` is also not a supported operator.

```
until [ "$COUNTER" -lt 20 ]; do
    printf "%0.1f\n" "$count"
    echo "COUNTER $COUNTER"
    count=$(bc <<< "$count + 0.5")
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER - 1))
    sleep 1
done > value.txt
```

Comment: Precisely what I was about to suggest: +1

Comment: I receive this error: `./test.sh: line 7: bc <<< "0 + 0.5": syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< "0 + 0.5"")`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? Try `count=$((echo "$count + 0.5" | bc))` instead.

Comment: I am using bash, With that I get this error `./test.sh: line 10: echo "0 + 0.5" | bc: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ""0 + 0.5" | bc")`

Comment: Ugh. I can't count. I did some copy/paste in my answer, and forgot to change `$((...))` to `$(...)` for the `bc` command.

Comment: One question, the first value is `0` the second is `.5` third `1.0`. Why isn't the second `0.5`?

Comment: `bc` is more about the calculation than the format. There might be a way to adjust the output for `bc`, but it's easier (given my limited knowledge of `bc`) to accommodate that with `printf`; see my update.