# substraction of variable having float value is not working

Tags: bash, solaris

I am executing below as part of bash script on solaris 10.

```
MEM_USED_PC=`prstat -Z 1 1 | grep -i sz | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//'`
MEM_TOTAL_PC=100

MEM_FREE_PC=$(($MEM_TOTAL_PC-$MEM_USED_PC))
```

but `echo $MEM_FREE_PC` gives below error:

```
100-6.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14222250/1030675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the calculator CLI, `bc`

```
MEM_FREE_PC=$(echo "$MEM_TOTAL_PC - $MEM_USED_PC" | bc)
echo $MEM_FREE_PC
```

Answer (score 1):

Since bash doesn't support floating point, you need something like awk to compute the result:

```
$ MEM_TOTAL_PC=100
$ MEM_USED_PC=99.33
$ MEM_FREE_PC=$(awk -v MEM_TOTAL_PC=$MEM_TOTAL_PC -v MEM_USED_PC=$MEM_USED_PC 'BEGIN {print MEM_TOTAL_PC-MEM_USED_PC}')
$ echo $MEM_FREE_PC
0.67
```