# Bash Comparing Whole number to Decimal Errors

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script in which I am attempting to compare a variable containing a whole number

```
VAR1=1
```

The real number to compare to, can be a decimal

```
VAR2=1.5
```

When I try:

```
if [[ $VAR1 -ge $VAR2]];
```

I am presented with a `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator`

The problem is, when I try the `>=` string comparison, the result is always false irregardles of whether it logically is or not.

My question is, how can I fix this and do the arithmatic comparison?

## Code Block

```
if [ $(bc -l <<<"$CPUUSAGE >= $MAXCPU") || $(bc -l <<<"$FREEMEM <= $MAXMEM") || $NUMHTTPD -ge $MAXHTTPD || $NUMMYSQL -ge $MAXMYSQL || $NUMPROCS -ge $MAXPROCESSES ]];
then    
    SendMessage;
    sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;
    echo "Message Sent";
fi;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two floating point numbers in a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point numbers.

Try `bc`:

```
(( $(bc -l <<<"$v1 >= $v2") )) && echo "v1 is greater than or equal to v2"
```

I have used some bashisms here, notably the `(( arithmetic context ))` and `<<<` as an alternative to `echo`ing the string to `bc`. The output of `bc` will be 1 or 0, depending on whether the statement is true or false. The message will only be echoed if the result is true.

The `-l` switch is shorthand for `--mathlib`, which as [hek2mgl rightly asserts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278932/2088135), is needed when working with floating point numbers.

If you want a fully-fledged `if` statement, you can do that as well:

```
if (( $(bc -l <<<"$v1 >= $v2") )); then
    echo "v1 is greater than or equal to v2"
else
    echo "v1 is less than v2"
fi
```

For the example in your question, you could use this:

```
if (( $(bc -l <<<"$CPUUSAGE >= $MAXCPU || $FREEMEM <= $MAXMEM") )) || [[ $NUMHTTPD -ge $MAXHTTPD || $NUMMYSQL -ge $MAXMYSQL || $NUMPROCS -ge $MAXPROCESSES ]]; then echo; fi
```

I've combined the two conditions in `bc` to save you calling the tool twice. I've also wrapped that part in an arithmetic context and used an extended test `[[` for the rest.

Comment: The arithmetic context is great! (My first first version wouldn't even work ( while it had already two ups :) )

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks, the reason for my delay was that I was trying things similar to your post but couldn't get them to work :)

Comment: now getting [: missing `]' and command not found errors, sorry, I am a bash noob

Answer (score 2):

`bash` does not support floating point operations. You could use `bc` for that:

```
if  [ $(bc --mathlib <<< "$var1 >= $var2") = "1" ] ; then
    echo "$var2 is greater than or equal to $var2"
fi
```

Note that unless you pass the `--mathlib` option, even `bc` would not support floating point operations.

Answer (score 0):

AWK can do the trick too:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR1=1
VAR2=1.5

if awk "BEGIN {exit $VAR1 >= $VAR2 ? 0 : 1}"
then 
   echo "$VAR1 is greater than or equal to $VAR2" 
else
   echo "$VAR2 is greater than or equal to $VAR1"
fi
```