# Shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Im having trouble formulating the following:
Im trying to use

```
echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l
```

inside an if statement like

```
if [$(`echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l`)=0]
then 
echo "bloop"
fi
```

however the statement comes back with the numerical result plus and error
I tried echoing the result before entering the loop and I get

```
./script.sh: [2.00000: not found
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have told you some of what's wrong on this one before you came here.

Comment: Spaces matter to the shell. You wouldn't write `echo"$var1-$var2"|bc-l` and expect it to work would you? You need spaces around the `[`, the `=`, and the `]` in that `if` statement. `[` is a command and it requires certain arguments (the last of which must be `]`.

Comment: You need a space after the `[`. In bash (and most shells) `[` is a callable program and/or built-in command. Without the space, bash doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You can also obviate the pipe through `bc` by getting bash to do the arithmetic itself, by wrapping it in $[ ], a la `$[ $var1 - $var2 ]`

Comment: @JonCarter, that's the antiquated Bourne syntax. Modern POSIX sh (and thus bash) math syntax is `$(( var1 - var2 ))`.

Comment: Question: Do you really need to be able to handle floating-point values here, or is integer math enough?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, var1 and var2 are floating-point values in my problem, I just need to check if the sum is zero. The BC command is working now but I think its rounding the numbers, -1.42 - (-1.42) is not equal to 2.

Comment: @Gio, if they're both printed with the same amount of precision, why not just use string comparison? `[ "$var1" = "$var2" ]`; no floating-point awareness required.

Comment: BTW, if your real question is how to correctly do floating-point comparison in bash, then that makes this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I think that would work better and Ill check the floating-point comparison, I might need it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if [$(`echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l`)=0]
```

you need to make sure you have a space betweeen the `[` and the `]` like this:

```
if [ $(($var1 - $var2)) -eq 0 ]
```

`[` is just an alias for the command `test`, so not using a whitespace after it will make the shell not interpret it as a `[` command.

Also the calculation you are doing is wrong (or better how you do it). A simple approach would be using

```
if [ $(($var1 - $var2)) -eq 0 ]
```

Note here that you do not write `=`, instead you use the `-eq` parameter for equals. The `$(())` does the calculation for you.

Have a look at the manpage for the `test` command: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test

Comment: You're only solving half the problem. Running the output of `bc` as a command isn't right either.

Comment: you are right. just thought about the obvious. Ill edit the post accordingly!

Comment: `[` is *almost* just an alias for `test`. They differ in that `[` requires a `]` as the last argument, and `test` doesn't allow it.

Comment: You could also write `if (( var1 - var2 == 0 ))`, if targeting only bash (and only integer math).

Comment: @KeithThompson: You are right. I thought that `[` was just a symlink to `test`. Thanks

Comment: @Nidhoegger, ...well, they usually _are_ backed by the same implementation (though as a shell built-in, there's no calling through to the filesystem or launching a subprocess involved), but that implementation checks whether its name is `[` and requires a closing `]` if so.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: On my system (Linux Mint 17.1, GNU Coreutils 8.21), `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` are two distinct executables, with `[` slightly larger for some reason. But yes, they certainly could be links or symlinks to the same file, with the program itself looking at `argv[0]` to decide how to act.

Comment: @KeithThompson, in both dash and bash the builtins are provided by the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if [ `echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l` -eq 0 ]
then 
echo "bloop"
fi
```

As @Nidhoegger explained in his answer about the error of `[` and `]` having space in after and before starting and closing brackets.

Also some error in your was:

```
$(`echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l`)
```

You were taking the output as variable name and trying to use that value `$(...)`.

Also by doing:

```
$(`echo "$var1 - $var2"|bc -l`)=0
```

you are assigning the value instead of comparing it.

Comment: Closer, but doesn't work with the left-hand side being a floating-point variable, as bash does integer math only.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what would you suggest?

Comment: `[[ $(bc -l <<<"$var1 - $var2") =~ 0(.0+)? ]]`, maybe.

Comment: ...well, since `2.000` isn't a valid variable name, `2.000=0` isn't a valid assignment... and even if the left-hand-side _were_ a valid variable name, the content would need to be `eval`'d for the shell to see an assignment there. In the context of a `test` command, `2.000=0` is just a string, and the default thing to do with a string is to check whether it's empty.

Comment: BTW, the expression I gave above (with the "maybe") needs anchors to be correct. As it is, it checks for a `0` anywhere in the number. `^0(.0+)?$` is less broken.

Comment: Thanks, this was some new info for me. I didn't know about that.