# Illegal Number when Comparing floats

Tags: sh

```
if [ 3 -lt 6 ]; then
  echo "It works with ints"
fi

if [ 3.0 -lt 6.0 ]; then
  echo "It works with floats"
else
  echo "It doesn't work with floats"
fi
```

Comparing the integers in an "if" works just fine.

But it doesn't work when I do the same thing with floating point numbers, and gives me this output:

```
+ [ 3.0 -lt 6.0 ]
/tmp/hudson7259224562322746826.sh: 11: [: Illegal number: 3.0
+ echo It doesn't work with floats
It doesn't work with floats
```

Comment: Bash doesnt support floats in that manner see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-a-bash-script) for a solution.

Comment: The question isn't tagged `bash`, but `bash` shares its lack of floating-point values with POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `bash` manpage (my emphasis at the end):

> `arg1 OP arg2` : `OP` is one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`. These arithmetic binary operators return true if `arg1` is equal to, not equal to, less than, less  than  or  equal  to,  greater  than,  or greater than or equal to `arg2`, respectively.  `Arg1` and `arg2` ***may be positive or negative integers.***

In other words, `bash` has no native support in comparing floating point values.

If you really want to handle floating point, you're better off choosing a tool that *does* support it, such as `bc`:

```
n1=3.0 ; n2=6.0
if [[ $(echo "${n1} < ${n2}" | bc) -eq 1 ]] ; then
    echo ${n1} is less than ${n2}
fi
```