# Why isn't my if statement comparing floating-point numbers working?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is my code, its pretty self-explanatory:

```
if [ 0.02779 -lt 1.972 ]
   then 
        echo "0"
fi
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Bash doesn't support floating-point math.

Comment: Bash only supports integer arithmetic. Floating point is not possible. You could use string comparison, of course, but that would give a wrong answer for values > 9, and probably in other cases.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8654051/1292652

Comment: ...on a different topic, `[ ... ]` is *not* part of `if` syntax. You could run it as its own command and use `$?` to check the result, for instance. `if` allows *any* command to be used (and thus checked), not only `[`.