# Bash concatenate less than sign to string read from file

Tags: bash, sed, concatenation, cat

The title says it all. I know that this is possible when not reading a file because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-a-bash-script) works. However, when I try to modify it to read a value from a file, I get weird results...

```
$ num1="1.291858E+01"
$ num2="1E-5"
$ echo $num1'>'$num2
    1.291858E+01>1E-5
$ cat sum.csv
    1.291858e+01
$ num1=`cat sum.csv | sed -e 's/e/E/'`
$ echo $num1
    1.291858E+01
$ echo $num1'>'$num2
    >1E-5858E+01
```

Edit:

I would expect the outcome to be

```
1.291858E+01>1E-5
```

And here is what I'm copying directly from the terminal

```
test $ num1="1.291858E+01"
test $ num2="1E-5"
test $ echo $num1'>'$num2
1.291858E+01>1E-5
test $ cat sum.csv
1.291858e+01
test $ num1=`cat sum.csv | sed -e 's/e/E/'`
test $ echo $num1
1.291858E+01
test $ echo $num1'>'$num2
>1E-5858E+01
test $
```

Comment: Quote variable expansions in double quotes as a matter of habit.

Comment: Also, I am unable to reproduce the last line. It yields `1.291858E+01>1E-5` as expected for me. I think you are screwing up something else you aren't telling us.

Comment: What is question here? Provide an input with a exact _expected_ output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lines end in control-Ms in sum.csv, presumably because it was create on Windows. Use `cat -v sum.csv` to see them and run `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.