# script in bash for sending mail if CPU exceeds

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables

CPU=$(sar 1 5 | grep "Average" | sed 's/^.* //')

if [ $CPU -lt 100 ]
then
   cat mail_content.html | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
else
   echo "Normal"
fi
```

when I am executing it I am getting the following error message:

```
./monitor_cpu.sh: line 6: [: 99.25: integer expression expected
Normal
```

I want it to be able to identify that the number x.x (99.25) will be recognized which is not happening right now.

Comment: For portability, you should specify `CPU=$(LANG=C sar 1 5 | grep "Average" | sed 's/^.* //')`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if `CPU` is not an integer, you can use `bc` to compare it.

```
echo "$CPU < 100" | bc
```

Then if the result is 1, the value of `CPU` will be less than 100.  So you can do:

```
[ $(echo "$CPU < 100" | bc) -eq 1 ] && echo yes
```

Or, you can convert it to integer with `printf`:

```
printf '%.0f' "$CPU"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-eq` does not compare floats, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash). Thus, you need to use `bc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables

CPU=$(LANG=C sar 1 5 | grep "Average" | sed 's/^.* //')

if (( $(echo "$CPU  < 100" |bc -l) ))
then
   cat mail_content.html | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
else
   echo "Normal"
fi
```