# Bash script to beep when temperature hot on FreeBSD

Tags: bash, freebsd, beep

I have been working on a Bash script to beep when the PC is too hot.
I have removed the beep to try identifying the problem.
What I have so far:

```
temp=$(sysctl -n hw.acpi.thermal.tz0.temperature | tr -d 'C')
echo $temp

if ["$temp" -gt "30.1"]
then
   echo "temp hot"
else
   echo "temp ok"
fi
```

My output is

```
54.1
temp.sh: line 4: [54.1: command not found
temp ok
```

Removing the `if` statement just outputs

```
54.1
```

so I think it's the `if` statement that's not working.

Comment: You should check your code with https://www.shellcheck.net to find syntax errors like this. Once the spacing in `[ ]` is fixed, your question becomes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double parenthesis `(( ))` to do arithmetic expressions, and since Bash cannot handle decimal values, you just have to remove the dot (as if you want to multiply it by ten).

```
temp=$(sysctl -n hw.acpi.thermal.tz0.temperature | tr -d 'C')
max_temp=50.2

(( ${temp//./} > ${max_temp//./} )) && echo "temp hot" || echo "temp ok"
```

Be sure to use the same format for both values (especially leading zeros, `54.10` would become `5410`).

If the format cannot be guaranteed, there is a second method, as mentioned by Benjamin W, using `bc`. You can send to this command a logical operation involving floats, it returns 0 if true, 1 otherwise.

```
temp=$(sysctl -n hw.acpi.thermal.tz0.temperature | tr -d 'C')
max_temp=50.2

(( $(echo "$temp > $max_temp" | bc) )) && echo "temp hot" || echo "temp ok"
```

Comment: Just dropping the decimal point requires you to know exactly how many digits there are after it. I'd recommend using `bc` instead.

Comment: @benjamin-w Yep, as told in my answer it assumes you knew the format (pure bash, bc not required). I edited my answer to provide a `bc` solution.

Comment: Would rounding / truncating be an option. It doesn't need to be that accurate

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is syntax error -- you omitted the space between the command (`[` -- `/bin/[`) and its arguments (`$temp`). The last argument of `[` must be `]` -- your script is missing a blank there too, which makes the last argument `"30.1"]`. The quotes aren't necessary here, BTW, and only make things harder to read.

This is a generic sh-scripting quation, it has nothing to do with FreeBSD nor with temperature-measuring.