# '4.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")' - but the code still seems to work. Why?

Tags: bash

My calculator generates the error mentioned in the title when I try to use the operator "/" as well as the numbers 4.5 and 2.

This is (just like the error states) most likely due to what's after the decimal point in 4.5, but I don't know how I could fix this and why the script actually manages to give me the correct result afterwards.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Operator: " operator
read -p "First number: " ch1
read -p "Second number: " ch2

case $operator in
 "+") echo "scale=2; $ch1+$ch2" | bc -l;;
 "/") if [[ $ch1 -eq 0 || $ch2 -eq 0 ]]
       then
        echo "Nope..."
       else
        echo "scale=2; $ch1/$ch2" | bc -l
      fi
      ;;
esac
```

Full output:

```
./script2.sh: line 9: [[: 4.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
2.25
```

Comment: which is line 11

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The line 11 corresponds to the line 9 of the displayed code, sorry about that! :)

Comment: I just posted an answer to this specific question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56415458/1745001

Comment: @ayygurl The reason it appears to work is that something like `4.5 -eq 0` causes an error, which is treated as "false", which is the right result... for the wrong reason. On the other hand, `0.0 -eq 0` will come out false for the same reason, but in this case it's the wrong result.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson Interesting, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Despite producing floating point results, Bash does not support other type of arguments than integers, so you need to rather invoke external tools like `bc` for your math or stick to integers only.

See the [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), section "6.5 Shell Arithmetic":

> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, as one of the shell expansions or by using the (( compound command, the let builtin, or the -i option to the declare builtin.
>
> **Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers** with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error