# Compare float numbers in Unix without bc

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have to write a piece of code which compares the available disk space with a pre-defined value and takes further actions based on comparison.

```
AVAILSIZE=$(df | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed 's/G//')
if [[ $AVAILSIZE -lt 7.0 ]]
then
    echo "[INFO] Not enough disk space available. Proceeding with cleanup..."
else
    echo "[INFO] Enough disk space available. Skipping cleanup."
fi
```

I have written this code. But the problem here is, `"AVAILSIZE"` is a float number and executing above throws error `"-bash: [[: 3.7: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".7")"`.

I tried using bc command but it throws another error `"-bash: bc: command not found"`.

Please help with this. Or may be suggest another approach doing what I intent to.

Edit 1:

This is my `df` command output. I am interested in value `3.7G` from first Filesystem result. Variable `AVAILSIZE` will have `3.7` value in it.

```
Filesystem                                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl_p10--centos7--template-root   16G   13G  3.7G  78% /
devtmpfs                                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                       1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                       1.9G  185M  1.7G  10% /run
```

Comment: Can you try `[[ $AVAILSIZE < 7.0 ]]`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-to-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash

It requires bc to be installed. On your system, it doesn't seem to be installed.

Comment: What is the output of your `df`?

Comment: @JamesBrown - Edited the question description with df output.

Comment: Use `df -k` and work with integer!

Comment: @Pacifist - That worked! Thank you.

Comment: @F.Hauri - Yes that would also work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about awk all the way?:

```
$ df -H | awk '                                          # I need -H for floats
NR==2 {                                                  # the 2nd row of df
    if($4+0<7)                                           # 4.1G+0 = 4.1 
        print "[INFO] Not enough disk space available."  
    else 
        print "[INFO] Enough disk space available."
}'
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Not enough disk space available.
```

Instead of `NR==1` you could define the mount point with `$1=="/dev/sda1"`.

Answer (score 0):

the below worked. Thank you @Pacifist.

```
AVAILSIZE=$(df | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed 's/G//')
if [[ $AVAILSIZE < 7.0 ]]
then
        echo "[INFO] Not enough disk space available. Proceeding with cleanup..."
else
        echo "[INFO] Enough disk space available. Skipping cleanup."
fi
```