# Bash If statement for non integer not working

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have a bash script and in it a if statement that I can't get to work:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3 echo "Please provide expenses for time period specified: "
4 read expenses
5
6 rev_pa=$(psql -U postgres -d crewdb -t -c "SELECT SUM(price) FROM work WHERE date_linkid BETWEEN 100 AND 500;")
7
8 blah=$(echo "$rev_pa-$expenses" | bc)
9
10 if [ "$blah" -lt 0 ]
11 
12 then
13        echo "Total expenses of $expenses exceeds total revenue of $rev_pa for the specified time period."
14
15 fi
```

I used expenses = 10000 and rev_pa = 12208.20 was the database output. The error message I get is:

```
./bash.txt: line 10: [: 12208.20: integer expression expected
```

Does anyone know how I can get this if statement to work in bash? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8654051/6770384 ?

Comment: `test` (and `[`) only do integer arithmetic.  Just do the comparison in `bc`: `echo "$rev_pa - $expenses > 0" | bc`

Comment: Thanks William Pursell. That has solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

12208.00 is not integer value.
-lt (and others) in test must be integers.

Comment: The OP *knows* their value isn't an integer -- that's why they put "non-integer" in the question title.

Comment: Also, see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), including the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".