# Bash, compare values

Tags: bash, comparison, precision

Trying to get this comparison to work in bash...

As an example, I want the second "comparison" to be true by setting foo=31.26 If the value in $foo is less then or eq to 33.75 **OR** greater then or eq to 11.25 then "do something". This doesnt work and none if the options are "true" no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

```
foo="31.26"
case 1 in
 $(bc <<<"11.25 > $foo >= 348.25"))  "do something";;
 $(bc <<<"33.75 >= $foo >= 11.25"))  "do something";;
esac
```

Comment: This might help: [How can I compare two floating point numbers in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8654051/3776858)

Comment: `bc` doesn't support chained comparisons (like `a > b > c`); split it up into binary comparisons and use `&&` or `||` to connect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
if (( $(echo "11.25 > $foo" | bc -l) || $(echo "$foo >= 348.25" | bc -l) ))
then
    echo false
elif (( $(echo "33.75 >= $foo" | bc -l) || $(echo "$foo >= 11.25" | bc -l) ))
then
    echo true
fi
```