# I am trying to comapre 2 numbers

Tags: bash, shell

When trying to compare 2 numbers which are decimal in an if condition, I am getting the following error

./cpu.sh: line 8: ((: 1 -gt 1.0 | bc : syntax error in expression (error token is "1.0 | bc ")

./cpu.sh: line 8: ((: 0 -gt 1.0 | bc : syntax error in expression (error token is "1.0 | bc ")

./cpu.sh: line 8: ((: 2 -gt 1.0 | bc : syntax error in expression (error token is "1.0 | bc ")

./cpu.sh: line 8: ((: 3.0 -gt 1.0 | bc : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 -gt 1.0 | bc ")

```
#!/bin/bash
val1=$*
for i in $val1
do
    if (( $i -gt 1.0 | bc ))
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: What arguments do you use when calling this script?

Comment: The correct way to do what I think you're trying to achieve can be found here:
[How Can I Compare Two Floating Point Numbers in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-can-i-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

`(( ... ))` expects an arithmetic expression. It doesn't handle `-gt` and `|` means *bitwise or*, not a pipe.

Arithmetic expressions can't handle decimals in bash. Using `bc` is one of the solutions, but you can't combine it with `(( ... ))` in this way. You need the output of `bc`, so use command substitution. `bc` doesn't understand `-gt`, it uses the traditional `<` and `>` to compare numbers.

```bash
if (( $(bc <<< "$i > 1.0") )) ; then
    echo $i
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use a greater than sign (-gt) in an if statement to compare numeric sizes, both operands should be numeric, otherwise the comparison may not be as expected. In this example, when the value of i is 1.1, you should be able to output this value, but in fact this code cannot output anything because using a greater than sign to compare strings is not a numerical comparison, and you should use commands such as double brackets or bc to perform numerical calculations.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
    if (( $(echo "$i > 1.0" | bc -l) ))
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

It is also important to note that using "$@" in the for loop to iterate through all parameters ensures that each parameter is handled correctly, even if it contains special characters such as spaces.