# Script runs fine in console, fail in crontab

Tags: sh

Following script works fine when run as root and it fails when run from crontab:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
/root/bin/memcached_guard: line 33: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

This is the "if" line. That script was copied from another server where it worked perfectly fine in crontab.

Any ideas why it is not working on new server? What annoys me is the fact I can run it OK from command line. Exit status is 0, so all is good. Redirecting stderr to stdout also shows no issues.
Both servers run bash, /bin/sh points to bash as well

(script checks CPU usage of memcached server and restarts it if there is a problem).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Max usage for memcached in percents
MEMCACHED_MAX_USAGE=70.0

# Where to send e-mail if there is a problem
MONITORING_EMAIL="xyz@xyz.com"

CURRENT_USAGE=$(top -bn 1 | grep -w memcached | awk '{print $9}')

#echo 'Currently using' $CURRENT_USAGE


# BASH does not support floating point numbers, so use Python
# Have to pass arguments as environment variables on same line so
# they are executed in same context as Python script
# Wrap into function for easier use

function check_usage {
MAX="$1" CUR="$2" python2 - <<END
import os
#import sys
#print "MAX Usage is " + os.environ['MAX']
#print "CUR Usage is " + os.environ['CUR']

if float(os.environ['MAX']) < float(os.environ['CUR']):
        print 1 
else:
        print 0 
END
}

if [ $(check_usage $MEMCACHED_MAX_USAGE $CURRENT_USAGE) == 1 ]
then
        echo "Memcached takes $CURRENT_USAGE% of CPU. Restarting" | mail -s "memcached problem detected" $MONITORING_EMAIL
        /sbin/service memcached restart
fi
```

I tried to use "1" instead of just 1 in if statement -- same problem.

tried to run script with
env my_script

I dumped cron environment on both servers -- they are identical. (added /bin/env/ >  into chtontab)
I then tried to run my script using env command and passed in environment variables dumped before. Works fine.
Thinking it has something to do with Python path to modules, I did a simple python script that was importing same 'os' module. Run this script using env with cron environment. No problem. Added this python script to crontab -- runs OK. So, not Python problem.

Comment: Your python script is getting an error before it prints, so the result of `$(check_usage $MEMCACHED_MAX_USAGE $CURRENT_USAGE)` is empty. You should quote your command substitutions. Paste your script into shellcheck.net

Comment: How are you running the script from crontab? The python error is because one of the environment variables is empty.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/how-can-i-compare-two-floating-point-numbers-in-bash for a better way to compare floating point numbers in bash.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for replying. Trid the service. Gave me a suggestion I tried. Still no luck in cron environment. Works fine from console or simulated cron

Comment: I added script to the crontab and output debug/error info into a file

Comment: "duplicate" is a huge understatement.

Comment: Using Python to compare two numbers is ... odd. Basic shell script literacy includes the basics of Awk (and `bc`, and `sed`, though that's not useful here).